# What does "Goldilocks scenarios" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody explain these phrases for me, please? this Goldilocks scenarios,come off, getting some traction there

"So all of a sudden you get **this Goldilocks scenarios** for Europe where the data is better, the macro looks better, the risk has **come off** because you no longer have this challenge of a potential very important election in France," he noted. "And so then that's when see really the euro-dollar **getting some traction there**."

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/03/22/french-election-marine-le-pen-loss-could-come-with-risk.html

Comment: I used these links: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/goldilocks

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+off

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/traction

Comment: I would put my reference links within the post itself. Meanwhile, the Goldilocks link you had found is fine for use here, I would use the first definition of "come off (of something)" and I would use definition seven of traction, based on the link you had provided.

Comment: By the way, political leanings aside, perhaps [this](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2015/04/what-happens-when-the-training-wheels-come-off-hillary-clintons-campaign/460818/) might help in understanding "come off" better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on context, the author is using the phrase "Goldilocks scenario" to imply that nothing is too extreme either way, but rather that everything is just right for this financial scenario.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldilocks_and_the_Three_Bears)

> Maria Tatar in The Annotated Classic Fairy Tales (2002) notes that Southey's tale is sometimes viewed as a cautionary tale that imparts a lesson about the hazards of wandering off and exploring unknown territory. Like "The Tale of the Three Little Pigs", the story uses repetitive formulas to engage the child's attention and to reinforce the point about safety and shelter. **Tatar points out that the tale is typically framed today as a discovery of what is "just right"**, but for earlier generations, it was a tale about an intruder who could not control herself when encountering the possessions of others.

---

To "come off" in this usage means to "be removed" - in [your reference](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+off), use this definition:

> 1. [for something] to detach from, fall off, or drop off something. (See also Come off it!. Of is usually retained before pronouns.) The paint came off the west side of the house because of the hot sun. A wheel came off Timmy's tricycle.

That the risk has come off means that the risk was greatly lessened, or completely eliminated.

---

And "getting some traction" means finding purchase; gaining a foot hold; growing in popularity; becoming accepted. See [entry four](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/traction):

> the support or interest that is needed for something to make progress or succeed; a product that is starting to gain traction among consumers

Comment: Hi, Davo, I haven't downvoted your answer or anything, but I do feel like this answer is a little incomplete based on the OP, which had asked for explanation for three separate phrases.

Comment: Ah, thanks. My oversight, based on the title. I will enhance it.

Comment: I agree. Had I not read the post again, I would have also missed out on the other parts myself.